# Bootstrap column layout ordering?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I've made an image because I think it best illustrates my problem

https://i.stack.imgur.com/w1ZX7.png

[image: example]

I would like the "Get a Quote" button to come up below the first column (shown by the arrow) if the screen size is `md` or `lg`, otherwise for widths of `xs` and `sm` the layout needs to be a single-column layout, with the two text blocks and then the quote button afterwards at the bottom.

I can put the button within the first column instead of it's own column and I get the layout that I want for the larger screen sizes, but then obviously when the second column wraps below the button will be in the middle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

quickest shortcut I can think of is to have 2 versions of the 'get a quote', one visible on md or lg under the first block, the other only visible on xs or sm on the bottom of everything.

or you can determine the placement with scripting and move it accordingly.

Comment: I thought of this (the two buttons), but as you said - its a shortcut at the expense of clean html. I will only accept this answer if there is no other suitable suggestions using only one button and pure bootstrap/css.

Comment: This is what I ended up going with

Answer (score 0):

I figured out another answer:

Assume the following HTML:

```
<div class='col-md-6 col-sm-12'><h1>overview</h1></div>
<div id='life'  class='col-md-6 col-sm-12'><h1>why life insurance</h1></div>
<div id='quote' class='col-md-6 col-sm-12'><h1>get a quote</h1></div>
```

and the following CSS:

```
<style>
  #life{
    height: 400px;
    border: 1px solid black;
  } /* for visibility reasons */

  #quote{
    clear: both;
  }
</style>
```

On a mobile device the DIV's will be lined up under each other, with the 'get a quote' at the bottom. For larger screens you can add the following CSS:

```
@media(min-width: 992px){
   #life{
     position: absolute;
     right: 0;
   }
}
```

the 'position: absolute' will make it take up no height in the DOM, thus putting the 'get a quote' directly under the 'overview' and the 'right: 0' will put the div on the right of the screen.

see this [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/9974/) (you'll need a mighty big screen though, since it's running the HTML in a frame :) )

Comment: I like this, and i think its really clever. I have a suspicion (haven't tried it) though that if the life column is absolutely positioned (and because its longer than the overview) this will mess up scrolling. If the content becomes longer than the viewport then you will only be able to scroll to the bottom of the left column and it will ignore the right column

Comment: if you don't mind one line of jQuery that's something that's easily fixed. Just wrap the 3 divs in a wrapper and set the min-height to the height of the 'life'-div. See https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/9977/

Comment: BTW, position 'absolute' isn't the same as 'fixed'. 'absolute' means it's on a fixed place on the document, which can be scrolled through, 'fixed' means a fixed place on the screen, this content will no scroll. Just check the jsfiddle to see if this does what you're looking for

Comment: I know (about absolute vs. fixed) but if the element isnt effecting the layout of the page, and it's the longest element, it wouldn't effect the size of html/body and it would just run off the screen? (aside: yes, the javascript you posted resolves this issue)